# The Wheeler-de-Witt metric as a probability measure?

Tags: cosmology, quantum-gravity

According to the [Wheeler-de-Witt equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93DeWitt_equation) arranged like this:

$$\left(G^{ij,kl}(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{ij}(x)}\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{jk}(y)}-1\right)\Psi[g]=0$$

(Summing over repeated indices and integrating over repeated variables).

Then the Wheeler-de-Witt "metric" is:

$$G^{ij,kl}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2R\det(g)}\delta(x-y) \left(g^{ij}(x)g^{kl}(x)+g^{il}(x)g^{jk}(x)-g^{ij}(x)g^{kl}(x)\right)$$

Now my view is that if $G$ is a metric of the super-space (phase space?) of the field $g$, then the probability measure should be related to $\det[G]$, treating $x$ and $y$ as continuous indices.

But it doesn't look like a solution to the equation. i.e. $|\Psi[g]|^2\neq \det[G]$.  Very roughly it looks like the solution should be like $\Psi[g] = \int\int G^{-1} Dg$

So it looks like there's two types of "measures" on this phase space. The Wheeler-de-Witt volume metric $\det(G[g])$ and the probability measure $P[g]=|\Psi|^2$.

I wonder what the interpretation is of the realtion between these two ideas? What is the difference between the so-called superspace of Wheeler-de-Witt and the phase space of the field $g$?

**Edit:**

Actually I think if we **define** the "metric of phase space" as:

$$G_{phase}^{ijkl}(x,y) \equiv \frac{G^{ij,kl}(x,y)}{\det G} \Psi[g]$$

This would satisify all the properties of being a metric of the phase space and having the probability satisfy $P(g) =\sqrt{\det(G_{phase})} = |\Psi[g]|^2$. Where $\Psi[g] \approx \int_{\partial g'=g} e^{-\int R[g']} Dg'$ or some such solution and $\Psi$ is assumed to be real.

Although not sure what a metric of phase space would be good for other than defining itself in the WdW equation! Which would be:

$$\left(G_{phase}^{ij,kl}(x,y)\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{ij}(x)}\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{jk}(y)}-\frac{\det(G_{phase})}{\det(G)}\right)\Psi[g]=0$$

Comment: amazing subject, and great question, +1. What's the interpretation of the dirac delta in the ansatz of $G$?

Comment: Well I'm assuming you take the functional derivatives twice over every point. The article is a bit vague on this point though... The equation is not well defined. If you did the derivatives over different points probably the equation would be non-local. Whether you sum over every point is not clear. Basically it means the super-metric $G$ is diagonal in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: if you wanted to spread it over a planck-ish distance, I suppose the $y$ would need to be written in the right factor with the $g^{kl}$ terms, so that the expression remains symmetric on $x$ and $y$

Comment: well it's only non-zero when $x=y$ so it makes no difference.

Comment: I haven't seen the Wheeler-DeWitt metric written like that (with a delta function), doesn't that amount to picking a particular choice of regularization of the double derivative?

Comment: @Alex it might do. I'm not sure.

Comment: For path integrals we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant#Defining_formulae) $\int_V\; e^{-\langle\phi|S|\phi\rangle} \mathcal D \phi  \propto \frac1{\sqrt{\det S}}$ so similarly we should have $\int_{\partial g'=g} e^{-\int R[g']} Dg\propto \frac1{\sqrt{\det A}}$ and then $P(g) =\frac{1}{\det(A)} =(\int_V\; e^{-\langle\phi|S|\phi\rangle} \mathcal D \phi)^2 =|\Psi[g]|^2$ that is I think as far as I can get if my wikipedia physics doesn't fail me, just wrote $A$ because not sure how write this in terms of $R$,$g$ and $G_{phase}$.

Comment: @dandide yep, that's the way of defining the deteriminant of a continuous matrix. It's kind of what you might "expect" the volume measure on a phase space to be, if indeed you could have some metric G on the phase space which isn't necessarily so. But the way the WdW equation calls G the "super-metric" is intriguing to me.